# Memory effects of synchronized keyword in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

This might have been answered before, but because of the complexity of the issue, I need a confirmation. So I rephrase the question

**Question 1** :  When a thread enters a synchronized block, the memory barrier will include any fields touched, not just fields of the object that I synchronized on? So if many many objects are modified inside a synchronized block, that's a lot of memory moves between thread memory caches.

```
Thread 1
object.field1 = "";
synchronized (lock) {
  farAwayObject.field1 = "";
  farAwayObject.evenFarther.field2 = "";
}

Thread 2. assuming thread ordering is correct
synchronized (lock) {
  //thread 2 guaranteed to see all fields above as ""
  //even object.field1 ?
}
```

**Question 2** : Is `object.field1 = "";` in thread 1 implicitly part of the happens-before relationship?

I hope it is but It might not. If not is there a trick to make it so without putting it into the sync block? It is hard to reason on the program otherwise
and it is not practical to put everything under the synchronized { }.

EDIT: clarification: object.field1 is not volatile and the question is "will thread 2 guaranteed to see the write of thread 1, at least ". My question is about memory visibility. For the sake of the argument, let's say only thread 1 writes to non volatile object.field1.

**The question 2 can be rephrased** as

"Will a synchronized block on a lock push changes made before to be seen by other threads synchronizing on the same lock? "

Comment: The answer is yes to both questions.

Comment: @shmosel I had the understanding that `object.field1` would not be a part of happens-before and `Thread2` may or may not see the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a thread enters a synchronized block, the memory barrier will
>   include any fields touched, not just fields of the object that I
>   synchronized on

Assuming that the fields of `farAwayObject` and `evenFarther` are always modified and accesed by obtaining a `lock` on the same object all around your application, all threads will always see the updates made to `farAwayObject` and `evenFarther` since `synchronized` enforces a *happens-before* condition.

> `//thread 2 guaranteed to see all fields above as ""`

The same cannot be said for `object.field1` without knowing how it was declared. Assuming that `field1` is a reference not marked as `volatile`, it will not be a part of the *happens before* relationship and threads may see stale values for it.

> I hope it is but It might not. If not is there a trick to make it so
>   without putting it into the sync block?

Yes. Mark `object.field1` as `volatile`.

---

Addresing your edit :

> The question 2 can be rephrased as
>
> "Will a synchronized block on a lock push changes made before to be
>   seen by other threads synchronizing on the same lock? "

AFAIK the answer is Yes, provided that the writing threads acquire the lock before the reading threads. Unfortunately, this is something you generally can't guarantee and that's why `object.field1` needs to be marked as `volatile` or the statement needs to moved inside the `synchronized` block.

Take a look at [JSR 133](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization) which talks about the cache being flushed to main memory when the thread **exits** a `syncronized` block. This should clarify things further.

---

Comment: see my clarifaction. If i don't want to set object.field1 as volatile. isn't the specific write of thread1 to object.field1 pushed to main memory when the synchronized(lock) is executed? If no. would that mean the JVM flags memory changes made under a synchronized lock? so as to only push those changes?

Comment: @Mordan See edit. Does that make things more clear? Let me know if it needs further clarification.

Comment: your link answered my question apparently. It is a yes. I am relieved. :) I have been searching the web for weeks but never found it. Great link ! thank you.

Comment: @Mordan Glad to be of help. I believe my answer would have made more sense quickly if I spoke about the `synchronized` block flushing caches on exit before I spoke about anything else. By yes, do you mean that other threads will *always* see the updated value of `object.field`?. That's not true as explained in my answer.

Comment: By yes.. Provided no other threads write to it, Thread 2 will always see "" in object.field because it synchronized on the same lock. Your link provided another gems. "Writing to a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor release, and reading from a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor acquire. In effect, because the new memory model places stricter constraints on reordering of volatile field accesses with other field accesses, volatile or not, anything that was visible to thread A when it writes to volatile field f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f."

Comment: Those comments prove the subject is tricky. Do you agree with "Provided no other threads write to it and provided Thread 2 acquires the lock after Thread 1, Thread 2 will _always_ see "" in object.field because it synchronized on the same lock" ? @CKing

Comment: @Mordan Yes. Your last comment is correct. That's what I explained in my answer.

Comment: OK then we agree :). In my case I can make sure Thread 2 does not run before acquiring the Lock. It is waiting.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) When a thread enters a synchronized block, the memory barrier will include any fields touched, not just fields of the object that I synchronized on?

Correct.  (Assuming that thread 1 and thread 2 synchronize on the same lock.)

> So if many many objects are modified inside a synchronized block, that's a lot of memory moves between thread memory caches.

Potentially, yes.  However, it is (probably) not movement between caches.  More likely, it is a movement from one processor's cache to memory, and from memory to a second processor's cache.  Of course, that depends on how the hardware implements the memory hierarchy.

> 2) Is object.field1 = ""; in thread 1 implicitly part of the happens-before relationship?

There is a chain of happens-before relations

1. The write to `object.field1` happens before the lock is acquired.
2. That happens before the writes to `farAwayObject` and so on.
3. That happens before the lock is released by thread 1
4. That happens before the lock is acquired by thread 2
5. That happens before thread 2 reads `object.field1`.

The problem is what happens if there is an intervening write to `object.field1`, either before the `lock` is acquired by thread 1, or by some other thread.  In either of those cases, the happens-before chain is not sufficient to ensure that thread 2 sees the value that was written by thread 1.

Comment: can you clarify in the light of my clarification. assume there are no intervening writes. Would you answer yes like shmosel?

Answer (score 1):

> the memory barrier will include any fields touched, not just fields of the object that I synchronized on?

Yes.

> Is object.field1 = ""; in thread 1 implicitly part of the happens-before relationship?

Yes, even if it is not volatile.

---

> The happens-before order is a partial order.
>
> The happens-before order is given by the transitive closure of synchronizes-with edges and program order. It must be a valid partial order: reflexive, **transitive** and antisymmetric.
>
> ([JLS 17.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.7))

Actions before a synchronization edge (i.e. The release of the synchronized lock) are ordered by program order and thus synchronized with the release. Transitivity says that actions that are ordered by an *acquire* of the same lock in another thread therefore has a happens-before order with both the release of that lock AND the actions preceding the release of that lock, whether or not it is inside the body of the `synchronized` block. The important thing to remember about this is that ordering occurs on actions (i.e. Acquire/release of a lock) not a block such as implied by the brackets of the synchronized keyword. The brackets indicate the position of the acquire/release actions as well as where a set of actions cannot be interleaved.

Finally, remember that happens-before is a "partial" order. It means:

1. Happens before enforces memory consistency when actions happen to come in the particular order (i.e. release/acquire, write/read, etc)
2. Happens before depends on stronger guarantees such as program order to produce the correct functionality.
3. Happens before does not prevent errors coming from interleaving of nonatomic actions
4. Happens before is the transitive relationship between the action and a strong action. (You can put the read of your shared variable outside the `synchronized` block as long as the write comes before the block and the read comes after the block). Stronger ordering guarantees also follow happens before ordering, but they also provide additional effects described in the spec.